# How can I make a videoview resume after a phone call in android

Tags: android

I'm making a video player using videoview. But while I run the app and view a video, after receive a phone call, the video restart. How can I make it resume after the phone call. thanks

Comment: Please provide your code for getting help

Answer (score 1):

Add `int videoViewPosition` field to your `Activity`and override `onResume` and `onPause` methods:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  videoViewPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  videoView.seekTo(videoViewPosition);
}
```

There's possbility that system can destory your `Activity` during phone call, so consider to use mechanism to restore state of `Activity`. Read more here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html